# Replacing items in a list with items from another list in R

Tags: r, list, csv, for-loop, merge

I have a column in a list with country codes in characters, I want to replace these with numeric codes. for the "decoding" I have a second list where the character country codes are associated with the numeric codes.

I tried gsub:

```
   for (i in 1:nrow(countries))
{gsub(countries$code3[i], countries$numcode[i], doc_report$nationality)}
```

I tried a for loop:

```
i <- NULL
n <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(doc_report)) {
  for (n in 1:nrow(countries)) {
    if(doc_report$nationality[i] == countries$code3[n])
      doc_report$nationality[i] <- countries$numcode[n]
    else
      if(doc_report$nationality[i] == "NA")
      doc_report$nationality[i] <- 000
  }
}
```

and I had something in mind with merge()

this is how the column looks like that has to be replaced

```
[nationality] IRL GBR ITA FRA POL BRA ESP GBR GBR GBR
```

this is how the second table for decoding looks like:

```
 [code3] AFG ALB DZA ASM AGO AIA     ATG ARG ARM
 [numcode]   4   8  12  16  24 660  NA  28  32  51
```

so in table one I want the numcode from table 2 rather than the code3 style.

Comment: Those things that you are labeling with square brackets need to be presented in a manner (code or dput-output) that unambiguously presents their structure.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer

Here's an example with data formatted like yours to make it clearer that it does work despite duplicate country codes.

```
library(tidyverse)
country <- c("IRL", "GBR", "ITA", "FRA", "POL", "BRA", "ESP")
codes <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
countries <- tibble(country, codes)

doc_report <- tibble(x=c("a","b","c","d","e"),
           country = c("ITA","ITA", "POL", "BRA","ESP"))

left_join(doc_report, countries, by="country")
```

The output of this code is:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  x     country codes
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 a     ITA         3
2 b     ITA         3
3 c     POL         5
4 d     BRA         6
5 e     ESP         7
```

Which I believe is the behavior you're looking for.

## Original Answer

A simple solution would be to use the `left_join()` function in the [dplyr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8) package and then `select()` to remove the unneeded column.

Let's say `doc_report` keys countries by code and country_codes is a tibble with 1 column of country string codes and 1 column of corresponding numerical codes, you could do something like this

```
## join the country codes
doc_report <- left_join(doc_report, country_codes, by="code3")
## remove the unneeded column
doc_report <- select(doc_report, -code3)
```

Does this make sense? Happy to expand otherwise.

Comment: o.k. I have forgotten to say is that I have around 200k entries in table 1 and that country codes appear twice or more times. the left join might have a problem with that. at least I get an error that might point to that. > doc_report$nationality <- data.frame(lapply(doc_report$nationality, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nationality, value = list(X.AFG. = "AFG",  : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 19301

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated the answer based on this concern. Let me know if is still unclear.